# Hide ng-Message on Reset form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, web-deployment

I am beginner use a AngalurJs and Material AngalurJs
I need to solution for a little problem
I need to hide the error messages when the user click reset button
I tried `$setUntouched` and `$setPristine`
that change state input but not hide the message
Also I tried `ng-if` and `ng-show` and does not works
Html code I used it for ng-messages :

```
<div ng-messages="formName.fieldName.$error">
     <div ng-message="required">...</div>
</div>
```

And js-code for reset form :

```
<button ng-click="onclear">Clear</button>

// on controller js file code :
$scope.onclear = function(){
   $scope.formName.$setUntouched();
   $scope.formName.$setPristine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are the possible issues that I see:

To call a function, you need to use parentheses with `onclear`:

```
<button ng-click="onclear()">Clear</button>
```

If there is a 'required' error for a field, the following code will always show the message, whether field is touched or not, dirty or not:

```
<div ng-messages="formName.fieldName.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">...</div>
</div>
```

To hide the messages based on `$touched` and `$dirty`, use something like this:

```
<div ng-messages="formName.fieldName.$error"
     ng-show="formName.fieldName.$dirty && formName.fieldName.$touched">
    <div ng-message="required">...</div>
</div>
```

Also make sure you included `angular-messages.js` file:

```
<head>
    <!-- include angular and whatever -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

And that you added `'ngMessages'` to the list of your angular dependencies when creating your application module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
```

If you don't do the last 2 things, `ng-message` and `ng-messages` attributes will have no effect, all the div elements will be displayed regardless of field errors (unless hidden by that `ng-show` I added).

Check out this example that I made: https://plnkr.co/edit/fuqsr6WRdBKoebPq1Igs?p=preview

In the example I bind values to the controller instead of $scope, that is why you will see that `$ctrl`, hope that doesn't confuse you.